# Yii2 Use activeCheckboxList() for displaying data

Tags: php, yii2

Deal All,

From this [yii2 docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#activeCheckboxList()-detail), Yii2 say :

```
A checkbox list allows multiple selection, like listBox(). 
As a result, the corresponding submitted value is an array. 
The selection of the checkbox list is taken from the value of the model attribute.
```

So, I have a master data like this :

```
$data= ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\estimator\TipeTank::find()->all(), 'id', 'nama_tipe');

Array
(
  [1] => Frame
  [2] => Beam
  [3] => Chemical
  [4] => Food
  [5] => Gas
)
```

Now from my model, I have this :

```
 $selected = $modelRepairEstimate->inspection->getLinkTipeTankToIrs()->all();

Array
(
[0] => app\models\estimator\LinkTipeTankToIr Object
    (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5293
                [inspection_id] => 3874
                [tipe_id] => 1
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5293
                [inspection_id] => 3874
                [tipe_id] => 1
            )



    )

[1] => app\models\estimator\LinkTipeTankToIr Object
    (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5294
                [inspection_id] => 3874
                [tipe_id] => 3
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5294
                [inspection_id] => 3874
                [tipe_id] => 3
            )
    )

 )
```

As you can see, in model have `tipe_id = 1` and `tipe_id=3`.
How can I make it to checkboxlist which is tipe_id 1 & 3 is checked ?

Please Advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use widgets like a "Select2" or try like that

//view

```
<?php $form = \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin()?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'id')
    ->dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\TipeTank::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'nama_tipe'), [
            'multiple' => true,
            'options' => $selected,
        ]
    );
?>
<?php $form::end()?>
```

// your controller

```
public function actionSomeindex()
    {
        //some other code ...
        $selected = array(
            '1' => ['selected' => true] , //tipe_id = 1
            '3' => ['selected' => true]   //tipe_id = 3
        );
        $model = new TipeTank();
        return $this->render('someindex, [
            'model' => $model,
            'selected' => $selected,
        ]);
    }
```

you can make $selected from your selected inspection. I dont know how work your function

Comment: Thanks, But I dont use form. I just wanna display it

Comment: Foreach($selected as $item) { echo "<?=$item</p>"; ?>

Comment: Ow sorry $item->tipe_id Like that